# ASP.Net Web API Controller Unit Test Fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a relatively simple Controller as follows:

```
[Route("api/areas")]
    public class AreasController : Controller
    {
        private IAreaRepository _areaRepository;
        private ILogger<AreasController> _logger;

        // Constructor.
        public AreasController(
            IAreaRepository areaRepository,
            ILogger<AreasController> logger
        )
        {
            _areaRepository = areaRepository;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetAreas()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogTrace("AreasController.GetAreas called.");

                // Create an IEnumerable of Area objects by calling the repository.
                var areasFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetAreas();

                var areas = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(areasFromRepo);

                // Return a code 200 'OK' along with an IEnumerable of AreaDto objects mapped from the Area entities.
                return Ok(areas);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all Areas: {ex}");

                return BadRequest("Error Occurred");
            }

        }
...
```

I am new to Unit Testing and am struggling to get the most basic of tests working. I am using XUnit and Moq in Visual Studio 2017.

To dip my toe in the water I wanted to test that the GetAreas method on the controller, if there were some Areas, would return an okObjectResult, but it doesn't!

Here's my test:

```
[Fact]
        public void ReturnAreasForGetAreas()
        {
            //Arrange
            var area = new Area
            {
                Id = new Guid("761317f6-f9d7-4fa4-a8fe-c6179daee3da"),
                Description = "Test Area",
                SortIndex = 1
            };

            var _mockAreaRepository = new Mock<IAreaRepository>();
            _mockAreaRepository
                .Setup(x => x.GetAreas())
                .Returns(new List<Area> { area });

            var _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AreasController>>();
            var _sut = new AreasController(_mockAreaRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object);

            // Act
            var result = _sut.GetAreas();
            Assert.NotNull(result);

            // Assert
            var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>().Subject;
        }
```

Let me know if you want any Repository or Entity details. I am expecting the problem to be in my misunderstanding of setting up the mocked objects, either way I can't see it.

Comment: Debug and check what type is actually being return. Then you can see if you are checking for the wrong type. possible error is being thrown and the bad request is being returned.

Comment: I'm getting a `BadRequest` object back with a `StatusCode 400`.

Comment: So what is a problem? Does some assertions fails? Or you've go an exception? BTW, did you set up an Automapper for your test project?

Comment: Then that means that something is going wrong in the test that is causing an exception. Most likely the mapper is crapping out.

Comment: AutoMapper, that's a thought. I have not configured mappings for the Test Project.

Comment: @TDC you should be injecting `IMapper` so as to be able to mock that as well.

Comment: Forgive me for being naive but are we not exercising the the Controller just like it would normally be used, including AutoMapper in the main Project?

Comment: @TDC Yes, but you are using the mapper wrong in terms of how the controller was designed in the first place. Unit tests have a habit of bringing bad design out into the light. Just because it works when you run it normally does not mean it was designed well to begin with.

Comment: There's always so much to learn. How, or where, should I be mapping the Entities to Dto objects?

Comment: Just like you have it there but instead of using the static `Mapper` you use the `IMapper` abstraction and just make sure to associate the abstraction with its implementation at the composition root. I am sure the documentation shows how to integrate with asp.net core

Comment: Check https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: For what it's worth, you should avoid wrapping huge blocks of code in a single try...catch block, especially when catching something as generic as `Exception`. It doesn't really help you find the issue since literally anything there could have thrown an exception of some sort or another. Either catch discrete units (i.e. try..catch repository access, then try..catch mapping) or catch and handle exception types explicitly.

Comment: Also, in general, you should never catch `Exception` unless you combine it with `throw;` in the catch block, i.e. rethrow the exception (usually done simply for logging purposes). Only specific exceptions should be swallowed.

Comment: I will investigate injecting Automapper as well as read up on better use of the `Try Catch Throw`. I appreciate the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug and check what type is actually being return. Then you can see if you are checking for the wrong type. It is possible an error is being thrown and the bad request is being returned.

another way to ensure that in the test

```
// Act
var result = _sut.GetAreas() as OkObjectResult;

//Assert
Assert.NotNull(result);
```

If using Automapper then I would also advise injecting the `IMapper` into the controller to be able to mock that as well when testing to avoid having to set it up just for tests. Tightly coupling to static dependencies can have undesired effects on the testability of your code.

```
[Route("api/areas")]
public class AreasController : Controller {
    private IAreaRepository _areaRepository;
    private ILogger<AreasController> _logger;
    private IMapper mapper;

    // Constructor.
    public AreasController(
        IAreaRepository areaRepository,
        ILogger<AreasController> logger,
        IMapper mapper
    ) {
        _areaRepository = areaRepository;
        _logger = logger;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetAreas() {
        try {
            _logger.LogTrace("AreasController.GetAreas called.");
            // Create an IEnumerable of Area objects by calling the repository.
            var areasFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetAreas();
            var areas = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(areasFromRepo);
            // Return a code 200 'OK' along with an IEnumerable of AreaDto objects mapped from the Area entities.
            return Ok(areas);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all Areas: {ex}");
            return BadRequest("Error Occurred");
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

just make sure to associate the abstraction with its implementation at the composition root.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(assembly1, assembly2 /*, ...*/);
```

Reference [AutoMapper extensions for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)